# Is there a way to create View Controller on a Tab bar programatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I basically have an interface with a tab bar controller interface (however it is not assigned to a class) and through the interface I created 2 tabs with two views.

I was wondering if there is a way I could do a third one strictly programmatically and then have a tab (the third tab) that will take me to that newly created view. I looked at so many solutions on this site and can't really find anything that works for me.

Comment: It’s very simple. You may need to show your efforts so people can help you go through .

Comment: Are you want to do it through storyboard or fully programatically???

Comment: Partly through storyboard and partly programmatically. Like I mentioned, 2 created on the storyboard and then one created programatically.

Comment: @E.Coms it is a general question. But I can show my code.